# Is it possible to move from plain elastic search to official .net client, NEST

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I am currently using PlainElastic as my .NET ElasticSearch client. 
I am consider moving to the official .NET client,NEST 
Questions?

1. Does NEST support SSL?
2. can we do common queries?
3. How to do common aggregations?
   does it take long time to move to nest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.NEST supports SSL/TLS. Just specify your url in `ConnectionSettings`

```
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("https://localhost:9200"));
var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool);

var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);
```

2.NEST supports **all** of the APIs that Elasticsearch exposes, including the entire query DSL. An example

```
client.Search<Conference>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Should(sh => sh
                .Match(m => m
                    .Field(f => f.Location)
                      .Query("Sydney")
                ), sh => sh
                .Match(m => m
                      .Field(f => f.Location)
                      .Query("Spektrum")
                      .Boost(2)
                )
            )
            .Filter(fi => fi
                .Term(t => t
                    .Field(f => f.Name.Suffix("raw"))
                    .Value("NDC")
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

NEST has features such as [inference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/nest.html) and [operator overloading](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/bool-queries.html#_operator_overloading) to make constructing queries even easier. Here's the previous query with operator overloading

```
client.Search<Conference>(s => s
    .Query(q => (q
        .Match(m => m
            .Field(f => f.Location)
              .Query("Sydney")
        ) || q
        .Match(m => m
              .Field(f => f.Location)
              .Query("Spektrum")
              .Boost(2)
        )) && +q
        .Term(t => t
            .Field(f => f.Name.Suffix("raw"))
            .Value("NDC")
        )
    )
);
```

3.NEST supports **all** aggregations. Here's a fairly involved example of a query against the stackoverflow data set, looking at questions tagged "dnx" or ".net-core" and created since 29 June 2015.

On these questions, a [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) is performed on the tags field, but only looking at the "dnx" and ".net-core" tags. On each term bucket, a [date histogram aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) is performed to bucket questions into 1 week intervals, with [a count performed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-valuecount-aggregation.html) on the number of questions in each bucket and a [Holt-Winters moving average aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-movavg-aggregation.html#_holt_winters) performed on the question number.

```
var response = client.Search<Question>(s => s
    .Size(0)
    .Query(q => +q
        .Terms(m => m
            .Field(f => f.Tags)
            .Terms("dnx", ".net-core")
        ) && +q
        .DateRange(r => r
            .Field(f => f.CreationDate)
            .GreaterThan(new DateTime(2015, 06, 29))
        )
    )
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Terms("tags", t => t
            .Field(f => f.Tags)
            .Include(@"dnx|\.net\-core")
            .Aggregations(sub => sub
                .DateHistogram("weekly_questions", dh => dh
                    .Field(f => f.CreationDate)
                    .Interval("1w")
                    .Aggregations(sa => sa
                        .ValueCount("count_questions", vc => vc
                            .Field(f => f.Id)
                        )
                        .MovingAverage("questions", ma => ma
                            .BucketsPath("count_questions.value")    
                            .Window(12)
                            .Model(mo => mo
                                .HoltWinters(hw => hw
                                    .Type(HoltWintersType.Additive)                                     
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```